# Display Price for Product Instead of Price for Sample

Tags: magento-1.9, price, product-attribute, custom-options, sample

I've built a site on Magento 1.9.2.4 that sells carpet. However, the client has decided not to sale the products directly, but sale samples of the product instead. But, there are two types of samples that may or may not be sold for various products. Product A might have available Sample 1 and Sample 2, while Product B might only sell Sample 2 and Product C might only sale Sample 1.

I added a custom option for the two sample types and added the fixed price for each sample type. But, if those options are checked, the product price gets increased, which is incorrect. So, my thought was to create a separate attribute called "Product Price" and set the real product price there. Then, I changed the Magento "Price" to $0 so the options are the only price value for the sample.

I need to show the "Product Price" on the page, but show the "Sample Price" in the cart once the product is added. However, I am having trouble getting the template to show the "Product Price" instead of the $0 "Price" that Magento uses as the default. Does anyone have a way of doing this well? I'll be happy to supply code snippets I've tested, if necessary.

Comment: use configurable products

Comment: @Minesh, I already have these as configurable products with 30+ colors as the associated products.

Comment: Are the samples associated products? We're suggesting that you build simple products for the samples and associate them as well. You could even build a configurable attribute with "New" and "Sample" as value, then use that, in addition to color, to build your configurable products.

Comment: In your scenario, if I have 30± colors and 2 sample types, wouldn't that cause a situation where I have 3x as many simple predicts as necessary? That'd be an additional 60+ simple products for just one product. Plus, how would that allow proper display of pricing?